# Running Android emulator from terminal on AWS EC2

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-emulator, kvm

I'm trying to run an android emulator on a EC2 t2.medium instance with ubuntu. Whe I try to run this:

```
/home/ubuntu/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5724,5725 -report-console tcp:5854,max=60 -avd Samsung_Galaxy_S4_Mini_API_19 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
```

I get:

> sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
>   emulator: WARNING: Ignoring invalid SDCard path: /Users/danielsierraf/.android/avd/Samsung_Galaxy_S4_Mini_API_19.avd/sdcard.img
>   sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
>   emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm

So I try:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

> INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
>   KVM acceleration can NOT be used

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

I've read on the internet something about enabling virtualization in BIOS. But I can't do that on EC2, can I? I this really the solution?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I'd look into [an HVM image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html), as that claims to support Intel's virtualization extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Well as the error states AWS doesn't support KVM extensions. I found out that this hardware acceleration is required for `x86` processors, but not for `ARM`, so I ended up installing my emulators as `armeabi-v7a` ABI and it worked. This work is for continuos integration so I don't need it to be super fast.

For those still interested in running a `x86` emulator on AWS I also read about [Ravello](https://web.archive.org/web/20180503074808/https://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/) to run the Android Emulator (with Hardware Acceleration) on Amazon EC2.

Comment: The link is dead :c

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20180503074808/https://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/

Comment: Thank you @crgarridos I've updated the answer with your link

Comment: the link is dead again?